# Has putting car tires over wings ever been used to protect the aircraft from airborne attack?

Tags: military, unmanned-aerial-vehicle

Recently Ukrainian bloggers have published videos, where Russians have placed the car tires on the wings of they parked strategic bombers (Tu-95), most likely to provide some protection against drones ([source](https://twitter.com/intent/follow?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw%7Ctwcamp%5Etweetembed%7Ctwterm%5E1698302027552436366%7Ctwgr%5E%7Ctwcon%5Es1_&ref_url=&screen_name=Tatarigami_UA), Twitter/X):

> What you are looking at is a satellite image featuring a TU-95
> strategic bomber covered with car tires. According to them, this
> should protect strategic bombers from drones

The post depicts this as a desperate action unlikely to work, but is it? Has this way of protection ever been tried, and if so, with which success?

Comment: Can you post the picture here as well? Not everybody has a Twitter account 

Comment: This is not my Twitter post. I am not sure if I have rights to do this. Simply car tires lying on the side, on the upper surface of the wings of TU-95, single layer.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like an attempt at [disruptive coloration.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disruptive_coloration)

The use of car tires likely has no significance beyond the fact that military bases tend to have a lot of tires in them which can be repurposed in a hurry.

Certainly camouflages have been used with some success many times.  Probably camouflages that attempt to protect a strategic bomber from drones are untested in war, since this is the first war where drones attacked strategic bombers.

Comment: May at least confuse the neural network of the drone computer vision, if present. It is likely trained to recognize wings without tires.

Comment: @h22 do you know if the drones fly by themselves only, or if they are human-operated/supervised? If it's the latter, then the effects are much more limited.

Comment: @ROIMaison most of the rockets likely do not need a remote pilot, so I do not think that a battle drone requires this kind of assistance by design. Fully autonomous flights are not allowed in civil environment, likely no one cares in the battlefield.